# Regex for multiple JSON string

Tags: regex

I am trying to work around regex expression for a complicated json string (multiple nested objects).

Here's the json string

```
    {
group: [],
lists: {
customer: {
lists: {
 "13067": {
                                id: "13067",
                                featured: { enable: false },
                                
                            },
                        },                    
                    },
                        
                },
}
```

Question is how to get value of 'id'? I tried `/\"id\":\"(\d+)"/` but this wont work. Plz help!

rgds.

Comment: Why quotation mark `"` around `id`?

Comment: That's not a valid json string. That's a json object. In a JSON string, each property-name has to be enclosed by double quotes `"`. So for instance `{"group": [], "lists": { ...}}` Also, in JSON specification, trailing commas `{"groups": [], }` and linebreaks are not allowed.

Comment: And you should not try to parse JSON with regex, but convert it to an object and access the properties accordingly ...

Comment: @derpirscher. Thanks for the pointers. I 'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
id\s*:\s*\"(\d+)"
```

But generally it's better to use some kind of Serialization and Deserialization api(
Jackson) for json structure. As you are mentioning complex json structure some kind of api use are more relevant.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. This atleast solves the problem theoretically..